# Incorrect time - time zone bug?

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What time is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it)

I'm not sure if this is a bug, so could someone please explain it to me?

Hovering over the username at the top of the page displays some stats and UTC time. The time appears to be 2 hours behind. I live in a GMT +2 time zone. So if my time is 12:20 on the site it displays as 10:20

Comment: UTC time != GMT time != your time zone

Comment: @George UTC == GMT except on sub-second level. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: @Pekka, sorry confused with GMT and BST.

Comment: @George yeah, I get those wrong all the time, too

Comment: @Pekka: According to that site GMT and UTC can be up to 0.9 seconds different. (yes i know i'm still wrong)

Comment: @George yeah, see my edit above :)

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

It's not supposed to display the time in your timezone.

Comment: ok but u didnt have to -1

Comment: I didn't. Also, reputation works differently in meta: [What does reputation mean on META and why? Is it different than SO/SF?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3718)

Comment: Now my weekend is ruined :-(

Comment: @DenysWessels why fret over the downvote? It hasn't even changed you rep (of 1)?