# What is the rationale behind limiting us to 200 reputation per day

Tags: support, status-declined, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Hi

I am just curious about why reputation has been limited to 200 per day.I know up to some extent it does not matter, But even if we get more than 200 a day there is nothing bad.

Regards
SSS

Comment: Do you speak Parseltongue?

Comment: SSSSSSSSSSS hsssssSSssSSSSss **HHHHHHhsss**

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap

Comment: none of  above comment i can understand !

Comment: I suggest that you read some Harry Potter, SSS.

Comment: There's something I would have never expected to catch myself saying...

Comment: They're references to Harry Potter stories, prompted by the sibilance of your username.

Comment: Good suggestion Welbo_g, This weekend i ll spend on Harry porter movies :) .

Comment: You might not get the same reference watching Harry **Porter**.

Comment: @SSS: Good idea. Some of the movies are pretty entertaining, especially the part where Voldemort turns out to be Harry's father.

Comment: @Adam, +1 for rationale

Comment: @random: But he might enjoy more, specially if he watches the sequels, *The Prisoner of Barley Wine* and *The Half-Pint Cream Stout*

Comment: declined as 'dupe'

Answer (score 9):

If it wasn't limited to 200 a day, Jon Skeet's score would continuously raise `ArithmeticOverflow` exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

[Jeff has written about this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/) and spoken about it in a podcast or two - and it boils down to two words: rate limiting. Without some form of rate limiting it becomes trivial to game the system and garner high rep with no real contributions.

For those that are genuinely contributing, yes it doesn't matter if you get 200 or 2000 rep a day - but for those that are not...

Answer (score 4):

To limit the amount of time anyone spends on the site. If rep was unlimited we'd all be on here all day everyday.

Ah - I see we are anyway

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/) are a [few blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/revisiting-the-daily-reputation-cap/) posts talking about the rep cap