# System doesn't encourage answers on sophisticated (not popular) questions?

Tags: discussion

I've been on StackOverflow for only a couple of months and I noticed that quite often (not always) when I answer a question that doesn't have a simple or well known answer and therefore requires quite some time to investigate and provide a solution, the answer doesn't get awarded. Event though it answers correctly the original question, the asker doesn't accept it because it turns out that the problem was with something else and the provided solution just doesn't work as is... Other people don't upvote it because the problem is rare and uncommon and they just don't care about it.

On the other hand, when a question is simple (like "what property should I set if I want to...") and the answer consists of one line of code it immediately receives some upvotes.

So, given that, I don't have any motivation answering "not popular" questions. Of course the motivation could be just to learn stuff and share the wisdom, but still...

What do you think?

Comment: This and similar discussions have been had many times over.  The oldest I can remember is [The bike shed problem and SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so).

Comment: @Bill - Thank you, I will read it. Before asking I tried to search for similar questions but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yeah, I understand.  If you haven't been around here awhile the term "bike shed problem" probably isn't the first thing you'd think to search for.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm tempted to say the driver should not be the rep. The driver should be the urge to give the correct answer; the rep you get should just be a nice reward.

I do think mods should ping the original poster, after some time without an answer being awarded, to remind them to do it, but that won't help with the one-time visitors who come, get an answer and go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree, the main motivation should be to give the right answer. But sometimes it is very disappointing that the asker doesn't respect your efforts. Especially when you spent a lot of time describing the solution...