# Priority given according to standard or level of questions that can be asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am not a programming **expert**. I want to know whether I can ask questions that might not be like somebody who is good in programming or an expert.

Is **less attention given** to questions asked from students or learners who are beginners or at an intermediate level even if the question asked is a valid question, presented nicely, not a duplicate and is relevant to the particular site (Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Meta Stack Overflow, etc.)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is less attention given...

Just the opposite.  We have this thing called the [bike shed problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so) where those types of questions tend to get *more* attention.

Comment: All the three answers are good and just this answer looks more comfortable/suitable to me, @Bil nice example                    thanks

Answer (score 7):

Actually, a beginner question that is valid, presented nicely, relevant, and not a duplicate (hard as those conditions may be to achieve) will be jumped on like a trampoline in a kangaroo daycare.

Why?

Because everyone knows the answer, so many people are likely to upvote a *good* answer to such a question, and the fastest answer usually gets the most votes.

Comment: +1 for the imagery.  Try as I might, though, I can't even find one video for a kangaroo on a trampoline, nevermind a bunch of joeys on one. :-(

Answer (score 5):

> **I am not a programming expert. I want to know whether I can ask questions that might not be like somebody who is good in programming or an expert.**

Yes, of course you can! This is a place to learn, and no question is a dumb question *as long as* it hasn't been asked before on this site. From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq),

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.

But you should also remember this (from the same FAQ):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Although there have been impractical questions that *have* been popular, those were either mostly in jest or known to be impractical and more a rhetoric question. There is no guarantee that such questions, if asked again, will be equally popular. It's more likely that it'll either be ignored or closed.

> **Is less attention given to questions asked from students or learners who are beginners or at intermediate level even if the question asked is a valid question, presented nicely, not a duplicate and is relevant to the particular site (stackoverflow, stackexchange, metastackoverflow etc)**

Again, no. You must remember that no one can be knowledgeable on every single topic. Even the wisest Zen master is untrained in the art of making spicy curry. If you look through, you'll find that the most well written, thoughtful answers are all for questions that are typically newbie questions.

If you're a student asking help on a homework, [different people adopt different guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), but the general attitude is that `it is better to teach a man to fish that to give him a fish`. So, you'll get helpful hints if you formulate your question clearly and show us what you've done and how far you've gotten, but all "I HAZ PROBLEM! CAN I HAZ THE CODE???" questions will be promptly removed.

Answer (score 4):

Questions from beginners and intermediate users are always welcome. A couple of things to note:

- If a question pertains to a homework assignment, please tag it `[homework]` and clearly state what you have tried already.
- Please spend a little time searching for an answer on Stack Overflow and Google. Often times "beginner" questions are answered by a quick Google search.

And, of course, all the usual guidelines for good questions apply.

As far as priority - that's up to the individuals who answer questions. While it's possible that some people might shy away from beginner questions, most will flock to them (as a certain reptile and a famous knife wielding, hockey mask wearing murderer pointed out).