# Reputation vs Trivial Questions and Closing of Duplicates

Tags: discussion

How do we discourage all these simple questions that are duplicates of other questions?  A lot of the more experienced people know that simple questions are great for getting lots of reputation from,  so way more incentive to answer it rather than close it.

Comment: RPG-like XP system. Level 30 characters shouldn't get any XP from killing rats. Puny level 3 characters should get lots of XP from killing dragons. Just my 0.02 USD

Comment: @GGG: You will surely be interested in this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104423/159251

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes indeed, I think that guy shares my vision :)

Comment: @ggg I know you are not entirely serious, but what makes a question a "dragon"? This leads us down the dangerous and uber-subjective path of "let's classify questions on a continuum from easy to hard". We could increase value of unanswered questions over time, but that would just incentivize asking difficult to answer questions that are "hard" for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I think that deserves more of a response than I can fit in a comment. Let me organize my thoughts and get back to you on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a question is, in fact, a duplicate, then closing it is the right thing to do. There's no point in building up a bunch of answers in multiple locations to the same question.

You express concern that there exists an incentive for people to answer these duplicate questions in the hopes of earning easy reputation, rather than voting to close them as a duplicate. I agree that this "problem" does exist, but I think it solves itself. Recall that the closing of a question is generally the first step toward its deletion, and that when a question is deleted, it takes all of its answers with it. That means that the answers those users posted in the hopes of gaining some easy rep will be [eventually] removed, taking all of that reputation gained with them. Even better yet, we're now [making these reputation fluctuations happen immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), rather than having to wait for a manual recalculation, which might have been quite rare indeed under the old system.

I don't really see a lot of duplicate questions that *miss* getting closed. I'm sure there are a few in some of the less popular tags, but there are enough high-rep users with close vote privileges on SO to make this not a real problem. Furthermore, once a close vote has been cast, those questions begin to appear on a list accessible to all 10k+ users. A significant percentage of us go through that list regularly, casting our own close votes where appropriate and hastening questions toward their impending closure.

If you *do* come across a stale question that should be closed, hasn't, and is unlikely to amass the 4 other close votes necessary, you should consider flagging it for moderator attention, explaining your rationale. If those of us who are conscientious and care do *our* part to keep the site clean, history tells us that generally things will work out in our favor, even if there are some users who try take advantage of the system.

Comment: If closed questions slowly move to being deleted, especially if trivial, then that solves a lot of the problem.

Comment: There's a flaw in your second paragraph, and that is that duplicates are considered pointers for their "master" question, and [their deletion is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates).

Comment: @Josh: Perhaps. I considered that, but my general feeling is that it depends very much on the particular question. If it's duplicated as a result of sheer laziness on the part of the asker and any reasonable search would have turned up the original question, I vote to delete it. If it's a particularly bad question (a "broken window", if you will), I vote to delete it. If it provides something positive in the form of a pointer to the original question—if it actually uses different terminology or describes the problem in a different way, then there's definitely no harm in keeping it around.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't think that we're in the majority.

Comment: @Josh: Since when should that bother me? :-) Anyway, my experience casting delete votes on SO is that there are a sufficient number of users who are in agreement about this so as to ensure that the poor questions I describe actually do get deleted. For questions with a score of 0 or less, it only takes 3 of us. And I suspect that the answers to the question you linked to are a bit out of date. Back in '09, we weren't dealing with a flood of really poorly-asked questions and otherwise useless content. I think the rules have had to be modified just a little bit, preserving the original spirit.

Answer (score 4):

> How do we discourage all these simple questions that are duplicates of
>   other questions?

By doing what we do now: down-voting to oblivion, closing, and--if necessary--letting the question ban algorithm do its job.