# How to limit disproporiately high votes on trival answers

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The bike shed problem and SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so)

I have noticed recently on SO that trivial correct answers to trivial question seem to get a dispropionate amount of upvotes.  While often correct answers with considerable depth to complex questions often receive nothing.
Case in point: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172735/how-to-cast-convert-pointer-to-reference-in-c)
Is there anything that be done to balance this?