# Why is this question not shown at "highest voted logo questions" even if it has a net vote of 210?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003841/974555) has a net upvote of 210 and has been favourited 71 times. It contains the tags `logo` and `turtle`. Yet if I look at the [highest voted logo questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo), it's not shown. Why not? I thought it might be because it's closed, but several questions that are listed at the highest-voted list are closed as well, so that's not it.

Is this some bug?

Comment: In such cases, always check the [revisions list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1003841/revisions). :)

Comment: @Pop I didn't know that kind of lock hide questions from the lists, so clicking the revisions list I saw "Historical significance" searched on Meta and shortly reached the faq.

Comment: Well, since I didn't know the concept of *historical lock* it's not obviously a dupicate to me. But see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155952/172266).

Comment: @gerrit "exact duplicate" isn't taken very literally on MSO. Any question that can be answered by an existing `[faq]` question -- or, to a lesser degree, any existing question -- is a target for being a "dupe" here.

Comment: @Pop it helped me find a short name for the lock, something to use when searching Meta. For me it was useful, not everyone knows everything. Maybe extra step but it does have benefit on most cases, for example when the question is just locked there won't always be a notice about it while the revisions list will show it clearly.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd on the one hand, I think I have a valid point and I'm just not communicating it clearly or you're missing it. On the other hand, I think both of us probably have better things to do than argue with a stranger on the Internet about something this trivial. So, I move that we both move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Historically locked question are not shown in the questions lists.

Originally, the top questions list was full of [bike-shed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so) that would be instantly closed if asked today. And these were allegedly setting a "bad example" to new users. So they were all locked [and knocked off the lists](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

But historically locked questions do appear in the searches.

[That logo question is at the top here.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Blogo%5D%20is:question)