# Notice on historical locked post should link to question on historical locks, not on closing

Tags: feature-request, historical-lock

A historically locked question such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003841/974555) contains a link to the FAQ. It would be more informative if it linked to [this question on historical locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/172266) directly, because the StackOverflow FAQ doesn't contain any information on historical locks and it's not immediately found when browsing Meta Stackoverflow either.

Comment: I'm all for that, however [it does appear here on Meta when searching](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Historical+significance&submit=search)