# Bounty for a question

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I just come across a very interesting *question*, which, due to [already-many-times-discussed disgusting nature of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so), scarcely will get any attention at all, not to mention any upvotes. So - I wish to spend some of my reputation points to distinguish an excellent question, just for sake of great justice.

Why can't we award a bounty for a question?

A trick just came to my mind - to award a bounty and to persuade an author to answer. But I don't like such a dirty game. Can't we make it square?

Comment: You could upvote it...?

Comment: Just ask the question yourself.  The oodles of rep, goodwill, recognition and respect you gathered over the years with your community members will ensure that it won't be closed again.  Wink wink.

Answer (score 9):

When you put a bounty on a question, it gets more attention. It is on the featured tab, and if it attracts answers (or edits to the question or any existing answers) it gets on the front page. Generally, if it is a good question, this results in upvotes. I have observed upvotes that exceed the cost of the bounty. Therefore if you bounty the question, the original asker is very likely to be rewarded with upvotes, with improvements to the existing answers, and possibly even with new answers. Sounds good to me.

The downvotes on your question are probably due to the phrase "due to already-many-times-discussed disgusting nature of Stack Overflow," - calling something disgusting in a conversation with people who care about it is not exactly a good technique for getting people to help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's makes sense. As of downvotes - I've other things to care of :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to directly award points to a question. But there are several ways to attract attention to a question, which will result (if it indeed is a good question) in upvotes (and possible excellent answers).

- You can put a bounty on it.
- You can edit the question to bump it (be careful with this one).
- You can mention the question in a chatroom.
- You can start a (relevant) topic on meta (not sure if that is going to work)
- You can share a link to the question on another community (for example your blog).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I never thought of the latter option which seems really promising.

Comment: You can even get badges for that, if you use the "share" link and gets lots of trafic.

Comment: Badges is another matter - There are few things in the world I care for less than those "badges". Unfortunately I am out of boy-scout age long time ago

Comment: Some people do anything for a badge ;-).

Comment: Yes. That's another disgusting feature of SO

Comment: Not disgusting, it is an incentive. And it works for some.