# Stopped receiving reputation for answer

Tags: support, reputation, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848663/else-or-return/2848685#2848685) question on StackOverflow today and I noticed that my rep stopped going up after the 12th vote. I am now on 19 up-votes and my rep has not increased since.

The question itself has not became a community wiki (nor is my answer) so I am wondering if this is this a bug or not?

Comment: Audit your reputation using http://stackoverflow.com/reputation . It will show you all of the reputation you've accumulated today: it's possible you hit the rep cap thanks to votes on other items. Check that and see if you haven't actually hit the cap yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you've received 28 upvotes today, so you've hit the reputation cap.

But you have the [Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard) badge, so shouldn't you already be familiar with this?

Comment: @mmyers: ah no I wasn't aware that your rep was capped! What is the reason for capping I am failing to see the purpose :S

Comment: He only has 247 rep, which means he's only hit the rep cap once. He probably received the Mortarboard for his rep-cap-hit today

Comment: @webdestroya: this is relating to my SO account

Comment: The purpose is to prevent Jon Skeet's rep from causing an integer overflow

Comment: +1 Fair point @Josh lol

Comment: @James: ["How does reputation work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Comment: In seriousness though is there a real reason for the cap?

Comment: @James: Psst, there is a search on meta too. ["Reasoning ..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap).