# Badge request: [2000 rep over cap]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

Could there be a silver badge for 2000 rep over the cap (earned but not received due to the daily cap)?  My thinking is that extra activity, even after the cap is reached, is to be encouraged.  I don't think this could be awarded multiple times, but I don't know.

Comment: I find this an interesting idea, +1.

Comment: Do you mean 200?

Comment: @Siva 200 isn't very hard; I have 1000 and don't even have Epic

Comment: @Michael: Pardon my ignorance, I am lost here. I thought 200 point is the daily cap. Sorry, what do you mean you have 1000?

Comment: I like the idea but not the name.

Comment: @Siva In total I've [earned about 1100 more rep than I've received](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/824/how-much-rep-would-i-have-if-there-were-no-rep-cap-fixed?UserId=309308), because of the rep cap. So I'd have your 200-rep version 5 times over

Comment: @drm65, I can't upvote twice ;)

Comment: @Michael: Got it. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @drm65 Actually 4 people did, but 5 people upvoted :). On feature requests people use voting to say if they like the idea, so 5 people like it and 4 don't

Comment: @Nick: Can you think of a good name?  I edited it out of the title.

Comment: @Michael: When I posted the comment, there were 2 vs. 2

Comment: @Siva: I think Jon has ~100000 rep over

Comment: @drm65: In total? More like 600K over. My rep report shows a total number of votes of 97597 at the moment.

Comment: @drm65: So do you mean 2000 rep over the cap in one day (i.e. 220 upvotes in a day), or in total over time?

Comment: @drm65: **[captain]** - naming is hard :)

Comment: @Jon: That's what I'm trying to think of now.  In SO, I'm sure we could make it for a single day, but in ELU, from whence I hail, only a couple people would ever get it.  The most I ever made was ~800-1000.

Comment: Maybe 3000 over time or 1000 in a day.  1000 in a day is hard, but so is Epic.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: wtfomglol for a minute I thought that query just returned the amount over the cap, not total rep.  About passed a brick.

Comment: When I first read this I thought it was about earning 2000 rep in a single day above the rep cap.  That would be a worth a badge.

Comment: It would seem the calculator link provided doesn't take into account any type of vote that would give "5" or "-1" rep, making me wonder if it's counting question votes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> My thinking is that extra activity, even after the cap is reached, is
>   to be encouraged.

One of the purposes of the reputation cap is to [get people to take a break](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54695/does-a-rep-cap-discourage-participation/54702#54702) from the site so they don't burn out; I don't think a badge for exceeding it makes sense. If they really wanted to encourage extra activity, they'd just get rid of the rep-cap, so I think your assumption is flawed.

There are badges for hitting it, but once you're 1 point over, there's no incentive to keep going (well, other than accepted answers and bounties). This badge would create an incentive to keep going indefinitely.

Additionally, you are encouraging "luck" which seems odd - one major reason people will hit a large amount over the cap is cause their post hit reddit or slashdot.

Comment: The rep cap is more like taxes in the post-war 1950s era.

Comment: +1 for the opinion, but your use of the concept *indefinitely* is fallacious, if it is a single-time badge.  You're right in that the rep over shouldn't be counted from just one day, though, since that would be only for fanatic users.  Only someone who would already be burning himself out would go for the badge within an insane time frame, such as in one day.  Normal, busy users might obtain it in a couple months.

Comment: I don't think this would cause people to go on *indefinitely* - if it's a one-time badge, the incentive will vanish after the badge has been earned.

Comment: And one can earn it slowly, if one is not a badge-monger.

Comment: But it's still *encouraging* something that they're trying to  *discourage*, while not encouraging any new beneficial behavior.

Comment: added another reason in my edit, feel free to remove it. declined cause of this.

Answer (score 7):

If you get 200+ upvotes in a single day, you will already get at least half a dozen badges like good-question, great-answer, enlightened, and probably a few tag badges as well.

This makes another badge look more like a badge-badge. A medallion to people who already have a drawer full.

Answer (score 6):

There are already three badges related to reputation cap: [Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard), [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic), and [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary).

I don't see any reason to add badges for the reputation users would have gained if there were not a reputation cap.
Consider also that users can gain more than 200 points in a single day because of accepted answers and (if I correctly recall) bounties. If a user's reputation was daily increased by 300 in X days, I think that would be equally a good result; the user would not get any badge, apart the already existing ones, even with your proposal.

Comment: I think the existing badges are actually better than the proposed badge.  they encourage you to spend time over multiple days exceeding the rep cap, rather than just hitting the site hard for a few days in a row to get one badge.

Comment: I agree; the already existing badges are better. The example I made was not about reputation gained in X consecutive days; I was just pointing out that getting more than 200 of reputation because of accepted answers should be something positive, which would not help on getting the badge proposed here.