# Should there be a badge for reaching all possible caps in a day?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

While on a quest for the new Reviewer silver badge on SF, I found myself very close to exhausting all of my votes and flags for the day, so I started answering questions. Then I hit the rep cap. Now there's not a whole lot more that I can do for the day other than editing poor content to work on Copy Editor.

I know that badges and rep should **not** be the driving motivator, but I still think that a new (silver?) badge could be useful for members that are hyper-active in all elements of the site.

**Conditions:**

1. All of the below criteria must be met within the same day.
2. You must hit the reputation cap
3. You must exhaust all of your close votes
4. You must exhaust all of your normal votes
5. You must (validly) flag at least 10 items

I'm a little iffy on the flags requirement. I wanted to say that you must use all flags, but that could be annoying for mods if someone is trying to "farm" this badge, and it hurts users with high flag weight since they get more flag votes. Maybe completely remove the flag requirement?

Comment: So I see a lot of downvotes, but no reasons behind them.  How about telling us what you don't like about the idea? I'm just sayin' . . . :-)

Comment: I see no harm in this, so have an upvote.

Comment: Also all [suggested edit votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited). I don't think it would be at all unreasonable to require 100% valid flagging for such a (gold) badge.

Comment: The badge should be called "Just five more minutes".

Comment: Part of the reason the reputation cap exists is to discourage people from spending all their time on SO (or any SE site). This badge is basically encouraging that behavior. Seems incompatible.

Comment: -1, this conflicts with my `Father` badge, which requires `You must (validly) have a job`.

Comment: @PopularDemand do you have citation for that? I thought the cap was so that a wildly popular question wouldn't skew a user's reputation and make them appear more knowledgable than they have proven.

Comment: @MarkM, it's well-known that the rep cap was introduced because of overflow issues involving Jon Skeet.

Comment: I'm primarily a SF user, so pardon my ignorance, but I was under the impression that anything related to Jon Skeet was impervious to things like overflows.

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54695/does-a-rep-cap-discourage-participation/54702#54702

Comment: @MarkM, indeed, but that's only because the Stack Exchange network is not hosted by Jon Skeet. If it was, reputation overflow would not be a problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - approving 30 edits on SO may be plausible, but on any other SE site, even seeing 30 edits needing approval over a day is a miracle.

Comment: @MarkM: I hadn't considered other sites; that makes me wonder how often one could legitimately use up all one's close votes, too.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's one thing I don't worry about. Bad questions are abundant everywhere. Low-rep or anonymous users wanting to edit things aren't, unfortunately.

Comment: You should perform edits at that point...  There's good (and plenty of) work to be done there...

Comment: @casperone - I do edit throughout the day as I see things that need it.

Comment: Encouraging maxing out close votes and flags seems like a great way to encourage unnecessarily closing questions and bugging the crap out of moderators.

Comment: @ben that's why I said they need to be successful flags. There's plenty of crap to close on SF every day, I'd imagine there's even more n SO and SU.

Answer (score 8):

Seems legit -- I'd say it should be a gold badge though - particularly with the flag requirement.

I'd also say that having an invalid flag should knock you out of the running to reduce the risk of annoying mods with people "flag spamming" in the hopes that 10 of them will stick...

Comment: Re: invalid flag knocking you out for the day - I actually meant to imply that in my wording, but forgot. Good call.

Answer (score 4):

You're contradicting yourself in your question:

> I know that badges and rep should **not** be the driving motivator, *but I still think that a new (silver?) badge* could be useful for members that are hyper-active in all elements of the site.

Being able to flash a badge is only the secondary objective of having said badges in the first place; the primary reason for having all of the badges that the SE sites do is to encourage good behaviors, and it looks like you're doing exactly what you should be already, for some of the badges in place:

- **Reviewing old/new/low-quality posts** to get towards the Reviewer badge.
- **Voting on questions (and answers)** to work towards the Suffrage, Vox Populi, and/or Electorate badges.
- **Flagging low-quality questions/answers** to work towards the Deputy and Marshal badges.
- **Answering questions** to gain reputation, and work towards any number of the reputation/score-based badges.
- **Editing questions/answers for clarity/other reasons** to work towards the Strunk & White and Copy Editor badges.

If you ask me, outside of doing justice for the communities you're participating in, isn't that all enough? I'm plenty happy with the number of badges that I can work toward while simultaneously cleaning up SO.

Also, like @PopularDemand cited, [the 200 rep cap is to discourage users from spending overmuch time here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54695/does-a-rep-cap-discourage-participation/54702#54702), and to encourage them to take a break every once in a while.

Comment: I'm not sure where the contradiction is. Just because we shouldn't be motivated exclusively by the badges doesn't mean that they aren't a part of SE.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time, there are already 70 different (currently attainable) badges that exist on Stack Overflow, and nearly as (if not equally) many on the other SE sites. I don't see a reason to implement a badge that has portions of many other activities that are already well-implemented in other bronze/silver/gold badges.

Comment: Didn't Kurt Gödel have something to say about the problems with consistent sets of statements?

Answer (score 1):

Proposed badge names:

- [B.F. Skinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_f_skinner)
- [Skinner Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinner_box)
- ADHD
- [Jipi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jipi_and_the_Paranoid_Chip)