# Should we have a new "Trending Users" reputation league that is weighted towards recent content?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The [reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2012-04-01/) is a good motivator to keep people participating. I think it would be interesting to see a new feature which showed a further split for **'trending users: reputation earned only for content added this week/month/quarter/year'**, excluding reputation earned on questions/answers that were written before this time period.

I've been gathering a few more statistics [here on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71784/trending-users-all-votes-vs-votes-for-recent-content).

In technical terms my suggestion is the equivalent to adding a new category where statistics are generated by adding the last 2 AND clauses on the SQL below (I believe most stats are currently based purely on when the vote was given):

```
and vote.creationDate >= '2012-05-01'
and vote.creationDate <= '2012-05-31'
and post.creationDate >= '2012-05-01'
and post.creationDate <= '2012-05-31'
```

The difference with adding the last 2 clauses is significant. E.g. for a top user...

- 751 votes received in May
- 290 votes related to posts posted in May

Obviously generating content that has lasting value should be rewarded but I think a new category which helps focus on recent content may motivate new users more as well as giving existing users a new challenge!

---

**Would anyone else find this new 'trending users' category interesting or motivating?**
Or am I just bitter/jealous because I only recently started actively contributing!? :-)

Comment: Do you insist on all that bold text? It makes your post pretty much unreadable.

Comment: Online version of the data dump for queries, in case you aren't aware of it: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Reducing  old rep by 50% will get Jon Skeet down to 250k, ten times what I have. Would still need 10 years to catch up. Why bother?

Comment: @BoPersson, You can easily win in a weekly or monthly view, if you are more active during the recent period- e.g. when Jon Skeet is on holiday :).

Comment: See also Jon Skeet's proposal to change reputation system so Votes on posts over 6 months old have no impact on reputation. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again

Comment: I like this idea! My answer is "yes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71798/rep-vs-new-rep-only) that compares the rank of users by rep using using all posts (T) vs just recent posts (N).* While there are some dramatic drop  (Nick Craver stopped posting  as much last year for [some reason](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/welcome-valued-associate-nick-craver/)) there are very few big climbers. For an average user like me it would mean moving up 89 places which isn't all that exciting.

```
User Link                     T_rep_Rank N_Rep_rank t_RepEarned n_RepEarned 
----------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- 
Jon Skeet                     1          1          41490       21283       
Eric Lippert                  4          2          15948       10992       
dasblinkenlight               7          3          11295       10807       
Luchian Grigore               10         4          9865        9497        
Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams        5          5          11412       8897        
David Heffernan               11         6          9629        8484        
Oli Charlesworth              12         7          9537        8105        
Jerry Coffin                  14         8          9209        7889        
ThiefMaster                   18         9          8234        7429        
Hans Passant                  8          10         11233       7289        
Jon                           21         11         7576        6606        
BalusC                        2          12         18435       6585        
jfriend00                     24         13         7097        6452        
Als                           26         14         6966        6447        
Darin Dimitrov                3          15         16725       6400        
Kolink                        30         16         6522        6219        
Mark Byers                    16         17         8258        6120        
Oded                          20         18         7668        5961        
geekosaur                     35         19         5922        5772        
SLaks                         13         20         9499        5585        
Michael                       32         21         6117        5577        
Binyamin Sharet               34         22         5960        5470        
Daniel Fischer                37         23         5693        5463        
Peter Lawrey                  28         24         6899        5234        
T.J. Crowder                  25         25         7059        5191        
Tomasz Nurkiewicz             33         26         5984        5154        
CommonsWare                   6          27         11333       5079        
Starx                         39         28         5372        5068        
Jonathan Leffler              23         29         7222        4834        
Quentin                       29         30         6607        4686        
Agarwal                       62         31         4505        4505        
minitech                      43         32         5099        4477        
agf                           46         33         4891        4461        
Lattyware                     65         34         4453        4453        
Andrew Thompson               44         35         5070        4395        
NiftyDude                     63         36         4494        4379        
Hovercraft Full Of Eels       51         37         4714        4336        
ehird                         56         38         4571        4331        
Tim Schmelter                 48         39         4822        4322        
Sven Marnach                  42         40         5128        4317        
JaredPar                      17         41         8241        4315        
Henk Holterman                41         42         5166        4313        
Louis Wasserman               58         43         4563        4298        
gdoron                        61         44         4506        4278        
Mat                           49         45         4780        4240        
RRUZ                          45         46         4965        4225        
larsmans                      50         47         4779        4076        
Niklas B.                     73         48         4231        4038        
Attila                        75         49         4116        4026        
KingsIndian                   77         50         4051        4011        
Vega                          78         51         4049        4009        
mKorbel                       68         52         4390        3999        
juanchopanza                  82         53         4013        3973        
Jonathan Sampson              47         54         4890        3967        
Joseph                        72         55         4237        3939        
Rob W                         53         56         4656        3838        
John Conde                    85         57         3979        3789        
aix                           70         58         4266        3786        
Baba                          89         59         3815        3717        
Marc B                        57         60         4570        3715        
hakre                         69         60         4290        3715        
Arion                         90         62         3802        3692        
Michael Slade                 99         62         3692        3692        
Nicol Bolas                   64         64         4465        3686        
paxdiablo                     27         65         6964        3675        
Rory McCrossan                93         66         3745        3600        
trashgod                      60         67         4532        3599        
Aaron Bertrand                87         68         3935        3546        
deceze                        55         69         4572        3541        
Óscar López                   96         70         3727        3537        
Guffa                         36         71         5828        3527        
cnicutar                      88         72         3836        3521        
Waqas                         99         73         3692        3457        
hmjd                          109        74         3560        3405        
F. Calderan                   114        75         3505        3400        
juergen d                     123        76         3421        3366        
amit                          104        77         3667        3362        
Justin                        81         78         4021        3353        
mu is too short               52         79         4701        3350        
Eugene Retunsky               115        80         3479        3349        
mellamokb                     111        81         3521        3341        
Matt Ball                     66         82         4448        3317        
Rocket                        107        83         3581        3297        
jamylak                       127        84         3360        3295        
Justin Pihony                 112        85         3509        3274        
Phrogz                        59         86         4557        3219        
Kerrek SB                     86         87         3948        3208        
Sergio Tulentsev              110        88         3544        3183        
David Thomas                  105        89         3626        3176        
Kaz                           124        90         3420        3170        
Shyju                         132        91         3270        3135        
Rob?                          131        92         3288        3130        
Ken Thomases                  140        93         3125        3125        
dhg                           142        94         3104        3079        
Justin Cave                   92         95         3760        3075        
Marko Topolnik                144        96         3097        3072        
Steve                         139        97         3161        3041        
dbaseman                      147        98         3062        2997        
Mosty Mostacho                138        99         3186        2981        
Dr.Kameleon                   153        100        3023        2958        
Mysticial                     95         101        3730        2935        
Sheikh Heera                  149        102        3052        2932        
BluesRockAddict               154        103        3005        2925        
Greg Hewgill                  19         104        7707        2920        
Gray                          130        105        3339        2919        
Mike Seymour                  136        106        3211        2898        
Nawaz                         116        107        3469        2886        
Marc Gravell                  9          108        10432       2833        
Elliot Bonneville             166        109        2815        2815        
BrokenGlass                   120        110        3451        2801        
Remy Lebeau                   133        110        3221        2801        
Phil                          152        112        3026        2796        
hammar                        126        113        3365        2795        
Stephen C                     74         114        4190        2791        
Amber                         76         115        4105        2789        
Ladislav Mrnka                38         116        5570        2775        
dash1e                        170        117        2755        2755        
Shedal                        171        118        2749        2729        
Tigran                        158        119        2935        2720        
Pavan Manjunath               168        120        2762        2717        
Guillaume Polet               165        121        2829        2689        
Ben Voigt                     129        122        3346        2648        
Richard J. Ross III           157        123        2955        2644        
assylias                      179        124        2659        2624        
Abhijit                       175        125        2709        2619        
usr                           162        126        2862        2612        
Habib.OSU                     188        127        2614        2594        
Dimitre Novatchev             98         128        3702        2586        
Jason                         117        128        3467        2586        
dbaupp                        176        130        2708        2573        
kev                           150        131        3046        2561        
Alnitak                       106        132        3596        2546        
Truth                         177        133        2705        2522        
ikegami                       174        134        2718        2520        
eggyal                        196        135        2518        2518        
Siddharth Rout                181        136        2645        2485        
MrGomez                       134        137        3219        2479        
gillesc                       202        138        2472        2472        
yamen                         203        139        2466        2466        
DCoder                        204        140        2455        2455        
F.J                           190        141        2595        2445        
am not i am                   193        142        2563        2438        
duffymo                       101        143        3689        2430        
James Kanze                   173        144        2724        2424        
Erwin  Brandstetter           169        145        2758        2398        
Ernest Friedman-Hill          191        146        2578        2388        
CodaFi                        180        147        2649        2383        
Robin                         199        148        2483        2378        
David Rodríguez - dribeas     148        149        3056        2376        
a_horse_with_no_name          155        150        2974        2354        
Curt                          194        151        2545        2340        
Jeffrey                       208        152        2400        2330        
hotveryspicy                  207        153        2403        2308        
Konrad Rudolph                83         154        3994        2284        
mattytommo                    222        155        2341        2261        
Servy                         224        156        2324        2239        
marc_s                        40         157        5366        2200        
alex                          118        158        3458        2193        
Mark Ransom                   137        159        3192        2191        
Tejs                          212        159        2384        2191        
jdoe                          246        161        2178        2178        
trutheality                   229        162        2305        2170        
JB Nizet                      156        163        2963        2168        
Kendall Frey                  239        163        2243        2168        
Justin Niessner               160        165        2917        2159        
Tim Pietzcker                 192        166        2571        2148        
ouah                          227        167        2317        2137        
Mark Reed                     253        168        2146        2126        
Michael Burr                  91         169        3763        2120        
bluefeet                      237        170        2269        2119        
Adam Houldsworth              219        171        2349        2114        
L.B                           238        172        2253        2113        
James Johnson                 225        173        2323        2108        
Adam Liss                     213        174        2382        2101        
stewe                         244        174        2189        2101        
phoog                         219        176        2349        2094        
Tudor                         209        177        2399        2079        
VonC                          15         178        8985        2068        
Mikael Eriksson               228        179        2315        2060        
Nikola Markovinovic           243        180        2190        2045        
Jack                          240        181        2226        2041        
Mystere Man                   214        182        2381        2030        
BoltClock                     94         183        3741        2015        
sandeep                       234        184        2275        2012        
joran                         211        185        2390        2010        
Péter Török                   217        186        2367        2005        
Nolen Royalty                 273        187        2018        2003        
Radu                          264        188        2083        1993        
Nicola Peluchetti             242        189        2217        1979        
Marco                         252        189        2154        1979        
okm                           276        191        2012        1977        
sch                           216        192        2378        1973        
Jonas Schnelli                275        193        2014        1969        
DaveRandom                    265        194        2064        1964        
zerkms                        215        195        2379        1956        
Daniel Roseman                122        196        3422        1943        
Oleg                          113        197        3508        1940        
Matthieu M.                   186        198        2623        1938        
senderle                      245        199        2185        1930        
Don Stewart                   172        200        2735        1910        
larsks                        290        200        1980        1910        
Chris Shain                   240        202        2226        1905        
svick                         206        203        2434        1903        
Richante                      309        204        1901        1901        
Bergi                         291        205        1978        1898        
Halley                        316        206        1890        1890        
Pointy                        164        207        2845        1866        
ildjarn                       296        208        1967        1861        
Perception                    283        209        2003        1858        
dave4420                      278        210        2010        1845        
Anonymous                     287        210        1985        1845        
Daniel Wagner                 303        210        1925        1845        
j08691                        285        213        1994        1839        
JRaymond                      312        214        1899        1834        
Li-aung Yip                   307        215        1916        1831        
Dougal                        325        216        1870        1825        
Alexei Levenkov               263        217        2084        1814        
Marcin                        288        218        1984        1808        
ManseUK                       298        218        1953        1808        
David Schwartz                270        220        2042        1804        
bfavaretto                    302        221        1926        1801        
zapl                          306        222        1920        1795        
Dondragmer                    348        223        1786        1786        
James Allardice               289        224        1981        1778        
Paul.s                        318        224        1888        1778        
Nitzan Tomer                  326        224        1866        1778        
danh                          330        227        1848        1768        
Brad                          281        228        2004        1766        
TLama                         274        229        2015        1760        
Eric J.                       286        230        1992        1752        
Andreas Brinck                301        231        1936        1748        
Matthew Flaschen              163        232        2860        1743        
sarnold                       235        232        2274        1743        
Boris Strandjev               333        234        1843        1733        
David Z.                      367        235        1729        1729        
Ted Hopp                      231        236        2290        1725        
axtavt                        128        237        3348        1720        
Ed S.                         258        237        2141        1720        
kindall                       269        237        2045        1720        
Nesim Razon                   374        240        1718        1718        
EJP                           232        241        2284        1710        
lazyberezovsky                358        242        1754        1709        
Bozho                         54         243        4581        1705        
Sinan Ünür                    247        244        2173        1703        
Josh O'Brien                  319        245        1885        1700        
izomorphius                   352        246        1768        1698        
bames53                       334        247        1836        1696        
Jasper                        218        248        2358        1688        
anubhava                      292        249        1972        1672        
James Montagne                281        250        2004        1671        
Bohemian                      260        251        2097        1669        
mihai                         388        252        1674        1664        
R..                           221        253        2347        1659        
Andrew Marshall               261        254        2093        1655        
ypercube                      303        254        1925        1655        
glenn jackman                 284        256        1999        1651        
Joey                          159        257        2920        1649        
Karoly Horvath                315        258        1896        1640        
Daniel A. White               280        259        2007        1636        
Joshua Ulrich                 300        260        1945        1635        
Martijn Courteaux             371        260        1721        1635        
DWin                          305        262        1923        1633        
Cal                           399        263        1651        1631        
Gaby aka G. Petrioli          253        264        2146        1623        
Joachim Isaksson              336        265        1828        1618        
Martin James                  407        266        1634        1609        
user1202136                   397        267        1656        1606        
pad                           375        268        1715        1605        
safarov                       351        269        1771        1601        
Adrian Iftode                 397        270        1656        1598        
Tim                           366        271        1731        1596        
sandy                         379        271        1706        1596        
Diego                         355        273        1761        1586        
joelparkerhenderson           368        274        1728        1583        
codaddict                     184        275        2632        1581        
Potatoswatter                 321        275        1874        1581        
imran khan                    356        275        1756        1581        
mprabhat                      414        275        1609        1581        
thg435                        365        279        1733        1578        
Joachim Pileborg              383        280        1689        1564        
adeneo                        386        281        1677        1562        
Matt Handy                    362        282        1740        1560        
Michael Dautermann            320        283        1878        1559        
thecodeparadox                419        283        1599        1559        
kuba                          432        285        1556        1556        
Luksprog                      372        286        1720        1555        
Florian Margaine              412        287        1617        1554        
ionden                        400        288        1642        1552        
Quassnoi                      121        289        3433        1543        
Botz3000                      392        290        1667        1542        
Zeta                          410        291        1620        1535        
jdi                           343        292        1803        1533        
Rob Napier                    210        293        2394        1529        
unwind                        201        294        2477        1520        
Caleb                         256        295        2144        1501        
Siva                          372        296        1720        1500        
Tim Cooper                    378        297        1708        1498        
Jack                          459        298        1494        1494        
ControlAltDel                 415        299        1608        1485        
Pranay Rana                   350        300        1779        1472        
Andreas Linden                468        301        1474        1459        
RepWhoringPeeHaa              413        302        1615        1457        
raju                          426        303        1580        1455        
Thiem Nguyen                  479        304        1451        1451        
Raymond Hettinger             363        305        1738        1448        
Jeff B                        382        306        1690        1445        
ninjagecko                    338        307        1821        1433        
Dems                          421        308        1588        1418        
nightcracker                  417        309        1607        1417        
Basile Starynkevitch          425        310        1581        1415        
Rafal Rawicki                 461        310        1490        1415        
MarcinJuraszek                471        312        1461        1411        
iambriansreed                 485        313        1445        1410        
barsju                        466        314        1476        1406        
phils                         391        315        1668        1403        
jpalecek                      449        316        1511        1401        
Royi Namir                    439        317        1538        1398        
David Anderson                473        317        1458        1398        
Branko Dimitrijevic           432        319        1556        1396        
debergalis                    506        320        1395        1395        
aleroot                       487        321        1441        1386        
tsherif                       513        321        1386        1386        
Raminson                      516        323        1383        1383        
Corbin                        495        324        1421        1381        
Phillip Mills                 501        325        1406        1376        
MichaelRushton                459        326        1494        1374        
dtb                           272        327        2028        1373        
Riccardo                      511        328        1388        1368        
nosid                         516        329        1383        1365        
JeremyP                       295        330        1968        1363        
paulsm4                       419        330        1599        1363        
Jacques Cousteau              375        332        1715        1360        
ulmangt                       528        332        1370        1360        
drew010                       395        334        1658        1353        
chris                         531        334        1368        1353        
Erik Philips                  483        336        1446        1351        
brian d foy                   277        337        2011        1350
```

*This is raw score only. It only includes upvotes, downvotes and accepts. Bounties, suggested edits, reputation caps, CW, deleted posts etc aren't considered.

As an aside if you really want to make a big splash on the user league for a time period just become a [bounty hunter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127021/is-excessive-bounty-hunting-good-etiquette)

Comment: With the ranks not changing much adding a 'Tredning Users' league may not add much value and would simply add more clutter to the site. Thanks for the query and analysis.

Comment: I've extended your query to show dynamically [last month](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119275/reputation-vs-new-reputation-only-for-last-month) and [last week](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119276/reputation-vs-new-reputation-only-for-last-week) compared results

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

I think leagues like "top poster this month" or "person with most accepted answers this week" would be valuable.

#### Answer in Depth

The leagues already track recent vs. past activity, but I think your question is more about "ratings deviations" for old content. While not directly applicable, the [Glicko system](http://www.freechess.org/Help/HelpFiles/glicko.html) on FICS tracks ratings this way, and for much the same reason.

I'm not against the idea of tracking new vs. old content in a new league--I certainly think it would be interesting to track who is *currently* posting great content, rather than just people with 3,761 upvotes on a cool answer from several years ago--but I think your question will get more upvotes if the reason for implementing it is more practical.

Categories like "top poster this month" or "person with most accepted answers this week" would certainly draw people's attention to quality posts that aren't part of their regular search patterns. Ultimately, more eyeballs on posts is good for the quality of the content, and perhaps encourage people to branch out into other knowledge domains.

On a related note, if one finds individuals who post a ton of great content, it might be nice for the leagues to offer a "follow" button, but I suppose that is really secondary. The primary objective is to let people know who might have something interesting to say, if it's not part of their regular topic search.

Overall, I don't think it's an *essential* feature, but it's a feature that I definitely support.

Comment: On SO I think it's quite important if the reputation leagues are to mean anything to people that aren't Skeet or Eric Lippert. So many (high quality) old posts means you get a handicap of 200 rep per day even without doing anything.