# New League Biased Towards Recent Content

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

#### Summary

This proposal is for a new league that would track *current* posting activity, rather than historical posts or necro-rep. There would be **no changes to the current system**; it would just be another way of looking at data the system is already tracking.

#### League Metrics

Specifically, the league would:

1. Having a sliding time window, rather than a fixed calendar period (e.g. the past 7 days, rather than a Sunday-Saturday calendar week). This would ensure that posting activity is averaged over the time period, rather than biased towards activity early in a calendar period or biased against activity later in a calendar period.
2. Include only new posts made within that time window.
3. Count upvotes/downvotes without regard to daily reputation caps.

#### Analysis

The first two items are pretty non-controversial, and have received some support in other comments, questions, and discussions, including (most recently) [Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again). The goal is provide visibility for active participants, without biasing the metrics towards historical postings.

This would not change the existing leagues, so folks with a great deal of historical content would still be highly ranked in those leagues. All that would change is that there would be one or more *additional* leagues to rank the data with a bias towards recent content.

Item #3 might be the most controversial, and could certainly be removed if the results would be undesirable for the community. This third item is intended to:

- Provide an incentive for high-rep users for whom the daily cap does not accurately reflect their ongoing contributions.
- Provide an incentive for new users who post exceptional content that isn't normally counted due to the daily rate cap.
- Provide an incentive to everyone to participate more and to post great content, even if it isn't counted towards earned reputation.

#### Please Vote

Please upvote if you support the idea of a new league. If you think the idea has merit, but you have an alternative implementation in mind, please post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'd vote for it if it tracked future contributions!

Comment: Nice. This gets +6 as [an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136078/148672) and -2 as a question.

Comment: @Flimzy You write an algorithm to track future contributions, and I'll offer my non-binding guarantee to include it in the SO codebase!

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Shhhh! You're not supposed to point out logical inconsistencies like that on meta. :)

Comment: hmm possible duplicate [Should we have a new “Trending Users” reputation league that is weighted towards recent content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134614/148672)

Comment: I'd love to see how I compare against Jon Skeet _recently_. :D

Comment: Did you just ask as a question a comment you made several months ago? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134641/187896 - That seems contrary to how this whole Q&A format works.

Comment: -1, leagues? We don't need no stinkin' leagues. Go answer questions, you'll gain reputation. No league needed.

Comment: I think that removing the reputation cap will skew the whole thing towards answers/questions receiving an insane amount of votes for reasons unrelated to content quality.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: Not very surprising - a question is seen by everybody following Meta, the answer only by the people who were already following the reputation cap topic. It's a self-selection bias.