# Why is there a maximum of 200 reputation per day?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Had a good day yesterday reputation-wise. But after a while the reputation count halted, although my answers got awarded.

Reading about it in this [SO info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reputation/info) I stumbled upon: "*you can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day*".

Why is that?

Comment: Yep, duplicate. Read it, understand it. By the way, I'm under the impression the cap wasn't there always. It looks like early SO participants gained very large reputation scores in the early days. We'll never catch up. Or am I being paranoid?

Comment: I don't know if the cap was in place all along or added in an early update, but in any case you can continue earning reputation past the cap through 1) accepted answers 2) winning bounties. It does take plenty of effort - but not impossible :)

Comment: @Kooilnc, accepted answers and bounties are excluded to rep cap, you can take a look how they have answered in their rep graph (lots and lots of accepted answers there), for eg, Jon Skeet's rep graph - http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph

Comment: I see. Johns rep graph is impressive, I'm inclined to think answering questions on SO is his daily job? I have a full time job and a small company, so I at least will never catch up ;) Well, it's not about the points, I'm learning a lot answering the occasional question here.

Comment: This will probably be my most serious comment on meta in weeks, but: he works for Google.