# Why is there a 200 rep limit per day?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

It seems having a limit on reputation encourages people to not try and earn as much reputation as possible per day.

Is there a particular reason for this limit?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's not about earning reputation, it's about helping to build an awesome resource.

Earning rep and badges is fun, but it can't be the most important thing, or we'd attract too many people for whom the gamified part was the *only* thing. By limiting the amount of rep you can get in a day, we allow the contributions of the people who really care about helping to outweigh contributions from people who just want to be in a gigantic... flag... waving contest.

Comment: But why should the effort put in be capped? If someone gets to 200 rep for a day they might decide to not bother answering questions for the rest of the day because they won't earn any more rep.

Comment: The theory is that if all they care about is getting rep points, then they're probably not really giving *good* answers, but rather just going for the cheap score.

Comment: I see where you are coming from but if people are going for the cheap score then their input is probably bad and won't get up-voted.

Comment: Note that I did not personally invent StackExchange, despite any rumors to the contrary :) This place has a long history, and as I understand it things have evolved considerably during that time. There was a lot of experimentation and the current formula has been fine tuned based on that wealth of experience. I would say it works!

Comment: @PriestVallon also be sure to read the answers in the linked dupe, lots of very good explanation and reasoning there