# Why is my reputation not increasing?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

I am receiving upvotes, but my reputation is not increasing. Why does that happen?

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699877/how-does-the-following-linq-statement-work/17699887#17699887) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701252/what-is-the-difference-between-following-two-statements/) for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Congratulations! You have hit the rep limit!

You have earned over 200 rep today. Only accepted answers and bounties will give you rep for today at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've reached the reputation cap. You can only gain 200 points from upvotes in a single day.

[What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Only [bounty awards](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty) and [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/accepted-answer) are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Comment: Will I get others points in the next day??

Comment: Once the clock turns over (Stack Exchange uses UTC) and you get more upvotes then, yes, you will earn more reputation points from upvotes.

Comment: The UTC day rolls over in 10 hours time.

Comment: Actually, I am asking about my lost votes. Won't I get???

Comment: @AtishDipongkor No, unfortunately the votes that you are not getting rep for today will not roll over to tomorrow.

Comment: No, the reputation you didn't get today won't be given to you tomorrow.

Comment: Why this reputation limit????

Comment: @AtishDipongkor See [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) And please note that multiple question marks don't make your question more important. One will suffice.