# What happens when a user reaches 200 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What changes, or what it is obtained, in my stackoverflow account (or any other) when 200 (total) rep is reached?

Comment: Implosion, followed by the mortarboard badge....usually, anyway.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges. (At 200 specifically, it’s an ad reduction.)

Comment: Thanks @minitech. I was blind, I were not capable to find the line of the "200 rep privileges" (I was watching only in the section "moderation", but the 200 rep are explained in the section "all"). Besides, I thought that some other special issues can be obtained with 200 (total) rep.

Comment: I've received 1 upvote and 1 downvote for this question. I disagree with both.

Comment: @pablo1977 to compensate you for both I have voted 0 on this question

Answer (score 2):

To find out what you unlock at certain milestones of total account reputation, see the [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page. At 200 reputation, you get the [reduce ads privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). Nothing else special happens.

You can access the privileges page from your account dropdown menu in the header:

[image]

---

There is also a 200 rep *per day* limit (from votes) you may have heard of, which is something entirely separate. That is mentioned in [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238):

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately. Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.

You can read about why that's the case in [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/152515)

Comment: My question refers to "total rep". (I have modified the question now)