# Was something changed in rep calculation?

Tags: support, reputation

For an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20099270/1671639) I received 10 votes and 1 negative vote but my rep is 90.

I remember

```
Upvote means +10
Downvote means -2
```

In my case it     `Upvote means +10` and `Downvote means -10`, is this a new change?  No big deal but just want to know about this behavior?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rep cap to the rescue!

> [image]

Or in words: the 10<sup>th</sup> upvote gave only +2 due to rep cap, so it's 92/-2 equals indeed 90.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: @Undo and at least 2 others, lol! :D

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this behavior.  Cool one.

Comment: Is this to prevent serial upvoting?  Any similar limitation is there for downvotes?

Comment: @Praveen the point of rep cap is discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/152859) in great detail. As for downvotes, in theory one can lose even 1000 in one day due to downvotes (500 different posts, 500 different users casting the votes), no cap for this. Feel free to start a discussion about it. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have reached your cap of 200 reputations per day from upvotes. You got a downvote on your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1671639/praveen-jeganathan?tab=reputation) one hour ago and just after that you received an upvote. Since your reached your daily limit of 200 reputations *(from upvotes)* so out of 10 reputations from the latest upvote only 2 were counted towards your total reputation. That is why you are seeing 90 reputations. 
[image]

Comment: Not a circle, not free hand and not red!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I suck at this stuff, this is the best I can come up with :)

Comment: So at least make it red... ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, finally

Comment: +1 now, you deserve it. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thanks finally figured out how to change the color .. For now

Comment: Next lesson: draw a circle/ellipse. :D

Answer (score 3):

It's because of daily reputation limits. You were only able to receive 2 more points for one of the upvotes.

[image]