# I can't get no reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

Currently, my answers are voted up, but I can't get my reputation points. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010968/selman22) is my account, and my reputation points are stuck at 2,270, but I'm sure I'm getting upvotes, so what is wrong with my account or this is a kind of bug or something?

Comment: Congratulations, you've hit the reputation cap!

Comment: @Selman22 *You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately ([source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.* - From the answer there

Comment: @Selman22 - It is a daily cap of 200 points from upvotes. If you get accepted answers you can still get +15 for those. At the UTC end of the day the cap is reset.

Comment: Which is in ca. 2h.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I understand thanks, this is really bad thing and annoying  :D

Comment: There are reasons for that, and I don't support all of them. Just search around for reputation cap.

Comment: I believe [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24370/190161) explains why a rep cap exist in the first place.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it's to keep Skeet from overflowing the rep field in SQL

Comment: If only Mick Jagger were a member of SE...