# Reputation calculation doesn't work properly

Tags: support, reputation

I earned 6 upvotes for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094496/what-can-i-do-with-a-hex-string-literal) **question's answer**, but, 3 * 10 was added to my reputation. I'm attaching the reputation tab screenshot, you can check in the question votes and reputation given. Under the answer tab, it show 6 votes given for the answer, and, under the reputation tab, only 30 was given. What's the issue?

[image]

Comment: You know up votes on questions are worth +5 right?

Comment: Congrats on hitting the daily rep cap! :)

Comment: @OGHaza, I'm not the questioned, I'm talking abt answer

Comment: Fair enough, the original post said question. In that case RJ holds the answer.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ : Can't earned more than that?

Comment: KugathasanAbimaran - You can but that would only be from accepts, bounties. From the votes, 200 is the limit for the day. This is `status-bydesign` :) I guess @Oded can edit the tags accordingly :)

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ : But, I can see people got 400, 500 reputation per day> How is it possible?

Comment: Those people have recieved bounties (or get a **lot** of accepted answers on that day)

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - Those are from bounties. As mentioned, bounties, accepted answers and answer accepts are not included in the reputation cap.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ, So all my effort was in vein?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - I suggest you read the answer in the link I've marked as duplicate. It'll clearly explain everything. If you want to know more, then [you can read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/216721).

Comment: @Kugathasan I'm not a huge fan of it either,  but its supposed to rate limit going up the levels. So you can't be close voting on your first day etc

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: absolutely not in vein. Even a reasonably new user like me gets a trickle of upvotes on questions I answered a while ago.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/216721)

Comment: @Bathsheba - Neither of us owns the content on SE. And I, personally, have no objection if you take some points from that link(if you give proper credits wherever necessary). BUT, SE generally doesn't encourage us the concept of answer duplication and specially of this kind. Again, personally, no problem. Please go ahead :)

Comment: "So all my effort was in vein?" Only if you believe the primary benefit of your effort was a reputation gain. I'd like to think the primary benefit is actually knowledge sharing, and that *doesn't* have a cap.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations. You hit the reputation cap! (Reputation points due to voting are capped at 200 per day.)

You get 5 reputation points per *question* upvote.

You get 10 reputation points per *answer* upvote.

See [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Comment: Where is in the SO to get 5 points for the answer?

Comment: OP made a mistake, he posted an answer, not a question.