# Is there a cap on reputation lost in a single day?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

On any given day, you can earn [a maximum of 200 rep from upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/159427). Is there a corresponding cap on reputation you can lose from downvotes? If not, why the distinction?

Comment: There is a cap; you can never go below 1 reputation point.

Comment: If your sole reputation change for the day is 100 downvotes, I think the least of your problems is capping it off.

Comment: The cap exists to prevent users from gaining privileges too fast without proper site experience. *Losing* privileges is far less of a problem.

Comment: @canon: excess rep-gain **is** a problem, because you gain additional privileges on the site. We don't want people with 0 experience with the site casting delete votes everywhere, for example.

Comment: @canon: there is also the 'give the rest of us a chance' aspect; if there was no cap, I'd never have reached position 25 on Stack Overflow in 2.5 years.

Comment: Beyond 20k, the reputation cap evens out the playing field a little; you need to provide *new* answers to gain bounties and accepted answer points to get beyond the cap and gain 'rank' on the site. This means that even accounts that hit the cap daily from old posts alone eventually fade away from the top rankings.

Comment: If you can come up with compelling reasons for why the site would be better off without a daily rep loss cap, then you're more than welcome to propose the feature.  As it is there is no compelling reasons for it to exist; features aren't implemented for no reason.

Comment: @canon: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447)

Answer (score 8):

The daily reputation cap exists to prevent users from gaining privileges too fast without proper site experience. *Losing* privileges is far less of a problem.

Besides, if a user is attracting *that* many downvotes (and it is not a serial vote
by one other user seeking out posts to downvote; these are reverted anyway), we really want to make sure that that user is not going to do too much damage to the site. Capping reputation loss would not benefit the site as a whole in such cases.