# Why not explain the reasons for daily reputation limit on the help page?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, help

In [**What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is explained as the reputation limit works, but is not explained what is the reason for this daily limit score to exist.

**My suggestion:** I believe it would be useful to explain on page cited the reason for this daily limit exists.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a lot of explanation for something that only the very curious are going to care about. When your help page goes from some quick bullet points to a novel-length document, you're going to lose your audience.

Or, to put it another way, the Help pages should explain how the site works and how to do things. The *justification* for doing certain things a certain way doesn't need to be there.

For the really curious, they can ask on the appropriate meta site. That's what they're there for.

To wit: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/21960)