# Soft opinion on changing the reputation cap

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

I'm writing in context to this question: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) about why we require reputation caps.

It's written there that a user who actually hasn't spent much time on the site can get to some features with the help of a few wonderful answers; while they certainly deserves the reputation but not the power that comes with it, they need to spend quiet a bit of time to vote for deletion or reopening etc.

I agree with this answer, but my question is if a user has been a member for many years, they know all about the Stack Exchange policies and all that, can't we just lift the reputation cap for them?

They have proved that they are a responsible member of the community and the problem which above answer talks about is also resolved for such a user.

Comment: I changed the tag to [tag:discussion] since your title says this is a "soft opinion", and this doesn't make much of the argument that we tend to expect from feature requests. If you believe this is incorrect, feel free to revert.

Comment: I'm not sure what the correlation is between preventing runaway reputation acquisition and account age or existing reputation. Can you explain? Why does someone getting to 10k mean they should have no daily limit on reputation?

Comment: @Catija I believed there should be no cap at all, but after reading the answers regarding why this is important I felt old mid-high rep users know about the site and it's features so they can be trusted upon(ofcourse there are exceptions but should try to minimise it's wrong effects)

Comment: Many trusted users who have been members for many years have hundreds of thousands of reputation points and reach the rep cap very often. If I understand correctly, you’re suggesting we remove the cap for them too?

Comment: @Laurel, yes that's the point I am trying to make, rep is hard to earn(atleast for lowly users ;-)

Comment: Considering there are plenty of users *with* reputation that still don't know how the site works, I'm not in favour of this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> if a user has been a member for many years

That doesn't mean they've been an *active contributor* for years. You could have registered a long time ago, not visited the site in years, and come back while basically knowing nothing more than an average new user who just signed up.

> they know all about the Stack Exchange policies and all that

How do you propose to measure this? You could look at their Meta posts, but most users who have more than a dozen posts on Meta have enough reputation that the reputation cap doesn't really matter.

Comment: Well if a user has something like 100k+ rep, and he seems to be inactive doesn't mean that they don't know about the policies. I wasn't particularly talking about old users, what i ment was old users with high rep

Comment: Those users have so much reputation the cap doesn't really matter to them.

Comment: @Arjun on SO I have hit the rep cap every day for several years running now. I don’t see any need to have it removed, because then why bother answering?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I’m surprised to hear that rep still motivates you. It stop motivating me a long time ago, and I have very modest rep, even on my primary site. I think rep incentivized me until 2k or so.

Comment: @DanBron not sure if I’m that bothered about rep or not, but without the cap there certainly would be no point at all; with the cap, *if* rep motivates you, then the only way to gain more than 200 points is to write new answers (for the +15 accepts) and / or bounties.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I still answer occasionally, for the joy of the hunt, the gathering and organizing of obscure information, for the thrill of *pinning it down*, to *know and to share*. Rep doesn’t factor in.

Comment: @DanBron my point was that the cap helps users that _are_ interested in rep to continue to contribute. Not that I particularly care for rep. I answer because I enjoy answering interesting problems, because finding the answer is my own learning style.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I guess I was responding to your original “[if not for rep] then why bother answering?”.

Comment: @DanBron I was referring to the cap, not rep directly, meaning that if someone were to be motivated by rep, then removing the cap would remove the need to chase it, at least for older accounts with enough posts to make the cap an obstacle.