# What does it mean when it says that accepted answers are immune to the reputation cap?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, daily-reputation-limit

I post an answer, and I get 20 upvotes. It isn't accepted. Then I post a second answer. It gets 10 upvotes and is accepted. Did I earn 215 reputation or did I get 315 reputation on that day. In other words, are upvotes on an accepted answer also immune to the reputation cap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reputation cap is set at 200 per day.

- If you get 20 upvotes you hit the cap.
- If you get 10 additional upvotes you get nothing.
- If you get an accept then you get an additional 15 reputation because the accept itself is not capped.

So yes, upvotes on an accepted answer are still capped.

Comment: Well, thats annoying @Robert Longson

Comment: Depends how often you hit the cap. If you're Jon Skeet it's very annoying, for most others much less so. The idea is to encourage the Jon Skeets of this world to keep contributing I suppose.

Comment: I generally post a lot in one day and then nothing for a few weeks so it is annoying. @Robert Longson

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Right or wrong, and maybe not applicable to all workflows, the rep cap was implemented by the founders for that very reason: to keep people from answering 400 questions a day to amass Skeet-level reputation on the daily... they wanted to encourage people to step away from keyboard, rediscover the sun, that kind of thing. I understand that doesn't seem fair to you, for your stated use case, but it's also unfair to anyone (Skeet included), too, who hits the rep cap on a day they're not even active on the site, or gets ton of rep from a single answer e.g. that hits the HNQ.

Comment: What is wrong with people answering 400 questions a day if they are all good answers @Stuckat1337

Comment: Well monopoly of contribution for one, but like I said, they wanted to encourage people to use their talents elsewhere, step away from the keyboard, enjoy the sunshine, etc. I imagine there was also some "don't get burnt out" in there. It's reputation, they're magic unicorn points that shouldn't have value, it's disappointing when people place such a high regard for it.

Comment: Lots of thoughts have been expressed about this over the years: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/1274780) and here: [Please increase the daily reputation cap on Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3709/1274780). Please read through those discussions because they do detail why it exists. I wasn't in their heads when they did it, and have no power to change it, and also have no desire to try to convince you other than to assure you it's not some arbitrary, sadistic rule to deprive you of reputation.