# When was the 200 rep per day limit added?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

It's common knowledge that Stack Exchange has a [reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/351462) preventing users from earning more than 200 reputation points in a day.

Has the daily reputation limit always been a part of Stack Exchange? If not, when was the cap added?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward to find out.

Stack Overflow was publicly launched on [September 15, 2008](https://www.google.com/search?q=stack%20overflow%20launch%20date) (source: a quick google search).

The [first version of the rep FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7238/1) contains a mention of the point cap dated September 24, 2008 (source: look at the revision history).

Even earlier than that, there is a [reference to it in beta from August 29, 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507022003/https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/21399-indicate-when-rep-cap-reset).

So yes it's been around the whole time since the public launch, and at least partially through beta.

---

Another source of info for these types of things is the search, sorted by time. For example, as early as [November, 2008](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8087/230261) there were references to the cap (source: the last page of a quick search for ["reputation cap"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=reputation%20cap) sorted by date).

Answer (score 2):

[This post from October 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20110812083942/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/35824-change-the-reputation-limit-algorithm?) says:

> ...the current "200 reputation points per day through voting" limit

So it existed a very short time after [Stack Overflow was publicly launched](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/). As for the public beta before that, no idea...

There's also [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1466/307988) to get rid of the limit from 2009.

So the answer is either "always", or "very shortly after launch".

Comment: Definitely always for the public version; I found one from [August 2008](https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/21399-indicate-when-rep-cap-reset).

Comment: @Jason touché... come to think about it though... the question is about "Stack Exchange" not "Stack Overflow" so the answer is definitely "always" :)